# how to Make file uploaded to s3 private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a rails app in which employers can upload files for a freelancer to work on.  i am using amazon s3 to store the files.  The problem is that amazon s3 assigns the file a url that if some has has, they can access the file.  Employers will often upload private files that only the freelancer should be able to see.  How do I make it so when an employer uploads a file, only the freelancer can see it?

Here is the file uploader code:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key => ENV['AWS_ACCESS'],
        :aws_secret_access => ENV['AWS_SECRET']
    }
    config.fog_directory = ENV['S_BUCKET']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `config.fog_public = false` option to make the files private.  And `fog_authenticated_url_expiration` (time in seconds) to add a TTL to each file URL.  See the fog Storage module for more info: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb